# Play Framework - Remove empty form entries

Tags: jquery, forms, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play! 2.3 Form object that is being bound from the request. The Form object basically looks like this:

```
val languagesForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "languages" -> list(text)
    )(apply)(unapply)
)
```

I have some jQuery code that adds a new `languages[1]` to my HTML form but there will always be an empty input submitted which Play! includes as an entry. How do I remove these empty entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter all the posted values in your controller method before you pass it to the form. The resulting code looks like this:

```
def removeEmptyEntries(map: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
    map.filter(_._1.nonEmpty).map { case (a, b) =>
      (a, b.filter(_.nonEmpty))
    }.filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
  }
```

Then, inside your controller you do like this:

```
def post = Action(parse.urlFormEncoded) { implicit request =>
    languagesForm.bindFromRequest(removeEmptyEntries(request.body))

    ...
}
```

---

The first filter on the `map` might me redundant but I added it just in case. Use this code as is and it should work fine. I'm using Scala 2.11